# Obfuscating Java in Gradle using yGuard ~ How to exclude enum?

Tags: java, enums, gson, obfuscation, yguard

My project obfuscates Java code in Gradle using yGuard.

I have a package of classes and enums that are being serialized with Gson.

Each enum value has a `@SerializedName` annotation, like:

```
  package com.package.whatever;

  import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

  public enum Enum1 {
    @SerializedName("item1")
    item1,
    @SerializedName("item2")
    item2,
    ;
  }
```

I have configured yguard on gradle to stop obfuscating the classes on the package where `Enum1` is located, like this:

```
ant.yguard() {
  inoutpair(in: shadowJar.outputs.files.singleFile, out: 
     "${buildDir}/libs/${shadowJar.archiveName}")
  rename(logfile: "${buildDir}/libs/yguard.log.xml", replaceClassNameStrings: 'true') {
    keep {
      'class'(classes: 'public', methods: 'public') {
        patternset {
          include(name: 'com.package.whatever.*')
        }
      }
    }
```

This is stopping obfuscating for methods in the classes within the `com.package.whatever` package, but it's not stopping obfuscation from happening within the enum values.

The resulting `yguard.log.xml` file ends up having records like this:

```
<field class="com.package.whatever.Enum1" name="item1" map="D"/>
<field class="com.package.whatever.Enum1" name="item2" map="E"/>
```

How can I avoid this obfuscating and cause yguard to skip the enum values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to filter by the class name `com.package.whatever.Enum1` and `fields: 'friendly'`:

```
keep {
  'class'(classes: 'public', methods: 'public', fields: 'friendly') {
    patternset {
      include(name: 'com.package.whatever.Enum1')
    }
  }
}
```

See [the `class` element](https://www.yworks.com/resources/yguard/yguard_ant_howto.html#class) (which also explains the access modifiers).